# How write a integration Test in Entity Framework to Test if data added to 2 related tables?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, integration-testing

I am writing Integration test in C# that Db is taking care by Entity Framework6. I have problem to test If data added correctly when data is added to 2 tables that are related by key.

Consider:

```
 Make Table - Id, name, YearId

 Year Table - Id, CalenderYear
```

Relationship:

```
 1 to many - 1 Year has n Make
```

This is my method in Integration test that I like to test if I can successfully add to both table:

```
    [TestMethod]
    [TestCategory("Integration")]
    public void ApplicationsContext_AddMake_ShouldAddSuccessfully()
    {
        // Arrange.
        var currentEntity = ApplicationsContext.Makes.ToList<Make>();

        // Act.
        var newYear = Fakes.GetNewYear();
        ApplicationsContext.Years.Add(newYear);
        ApplicationsContext.SaveChanges();



        var newMake = Fakes.GetNewMake();
        ApplicationsContext.Makes.Add(newMake);
        ApplicationsContext.SaveChanges();

        // Assert.
        var entityAfterOperation = ApplicationsContext.Makes.ToList<Make>();
        Assert.IsTrue(currentEntity.Count < entityAfterOperation.Count);
    }
```

This is my Fake class:

```
 public static Year GetNewYear()
       {
        var newYear = new Year()
        {
            CalendarYear = 2015
        };
        return newYear;
       }

     public static Make GetNewMake()
      {
        var newMake = new Make()
        {
            Name = "Toyota",
            Description = "This is Make Description",

        };
        return newMake;
      }
```

This is not working as I really don'y know how to send the Id of Year to Make?
This is the error I am getting:

```
   {"Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ_Year_CalendarYear'. Cannot insert  duplicate key in object 'Common.Year'. The duplicate key value is (2015).\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not relating the Year and Make that you're creating when you add them to the database.

So before you add them, you should add the `newMake` to the `newYear`.

```
var newYear = Fakes.GetNewYear();
newYear.Makes.Add(Fakes.GetNewMake());

ApplicationsContext.Years.Add(newYear);
ApplicationsContext.SaveChanges();
```

When you do this before saving changes, both are added to the database in one shot.